# Debug Symbol in Object file

Tags: c, linux

I have compiled a test c program and checked the size. It is **8504 B**. I have compiled it again with "-g" symbol then the size is **9544B**. 
Now i have used "**strip --strip-debug**" to remove debug symbol from **9544B**. I have expected that the size will be 9KB But it is **8390B**. Why i am not able to get  **8504 B** after removing debug symbols?

Comment: Isn't 8390B less than 8504B? Why are you complaining?

Comment: "I have expected that the size will be 9KB" why? "Why i am not able to get 8504 B after removing debug symbols?" you get less, you should be happy ;) compare results (differences) of `nm` or `strings` tools after and before stripping + -g option